# Magenot 2.4 custom routes does not working. All time i get 404 error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento-community

Am crazy or what? Can somebody inspect my code and tell me what I do wrong?

**I try examples from the official documentation:**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#router-class
and getting **404 Not Found**

**Also I try to write some module like from here:**

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module

When I put this mageplaza module in my `app/code` directory all works fine. I see one difference between the Magepaza module router and router from the official documentation. Mageplaza does not use the `Controller\Router` class and does not use an extra configuration in `app\fronted\di.xml` for configuring custom routes. They just declare a new route with **frontName** and **moduleName** in `fronted\routes.xml` and everything works well.

I rewrote code from mageplaza module to my new module. All code is the some but still not working.

After all changes I clear cache, cache flushed, module:upgrade.

The module is enabled.

The module also exists in the `setup_module` database table.

Check my code

**Module directory structure**

```
│   composer.json
│   registration.php    
│
└───app
│   │      
│   └───Learing
│       │   
│       └───ModuleRoute  
│           │
│           └───Controller
│           │    │
│           │    └───Index    
│           │        │
│           │        └───Index.php  
│           └───etc
│               │
│               └───module.xml
│               │
│               └───fronted
│               │      │
│               │      └───routes.xml
│               │ 
│               └
│               view
│               │
│               └───fronted
│                   │
│                   └───layout 
│                       └───moduleroute_index_index.xml
```

**Learing/ModuleRoute/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "learing/moduleroute",
  "description": "",

  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "My License",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Hi",
      "email": "hi@myemail.com",
      "role": "Leader"
    }
  ],

  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Learing\\ModuleRoute\\": ""
    }
  }

}
```

**/Learing/ModuleRoute/registration.php**

```
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Learing_ModuleRoute', __DIR__);
```

**Learing/ModuleRoute/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learing_ModuleRoute" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

Here i also try to remove `setup_version` but again all is the some!

**Learing/ModuleRoute/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

</config>
```

**Learing/ModuleRoute/etc/fronted/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="moduleroute" frontName="moduleroute">
            <module name="Learing_ModuleRoute" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Learing\ModuleRoute\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learing\ModuleRoute\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    private $pageFactory;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(PageFactory $pageFactory, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
   }
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Learing/ModuleRoute/view/fronted/layout/moduleroute_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Routing Page</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**bin/magento cache:flush**

```
ivan@Ivans-MacBook-Pro project-community-edition % bin/magento module:status Learing_ModuleRoute
Learing_ModuleRoute: Module is enabled
```

I really don't know what is wrong here?? all write all some code just different namespace and names?

**This also not working!**

I try an example from doc

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#router-class

I create a new `Controller/Router.php` class and update `fronted/di.xml` and all is the some 404

**Learing/ModuleRoute/Controller/Router.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learing\ModuleRoute\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface;

class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    private $actionFactory;
    private $response;
 
    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->response = $response;
    }
 
    public function match(RequestInterface $request): ?ActionInterface
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if (strpos($identifier, 'moduleroute') !== false) {
            $request->setModuleName('Learing_ModuleRoute'); 
            // also try this $request->setModuleName('learing');
            $request->setControllerName('Index'); // also try lowercase
            $request->setActionName('index');

            return $this->actionFactory->create(Forward::class, ['request' => $request]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Learing/ModuleRoute/etc/fronted/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="routingExample" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Learing\ModuleRoute\Controller\Router</item>
                        <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>
```

** 404 Not Found **

```
http://localhost/moduleroute/

http://localhost/moduleroute/index/

http://localhost/learing/moduleroute/index/index
```

Comment: TLTR. I see typo in "fronted" - should be "frontend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please change your folder name `fronted` to `frontend`.

and run

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Rejesh come and slap me in face please!

Comment: Yes coming ... hahaha

Comment: I hate when is this happeing. I spend 5 hours to checking everything. Also i read files and directories names and i dont see mistake in one word. B.W thanks

Comment: sometime it's happend dude. glad It's working now

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change code of controller as below**

> Learing\ModuleRoute\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Learing\ModuleRoute\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    /**
     * Default
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        //$this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Site Homebanner'));
         
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: No this example give the some result. i already try that yesterday.

Comment: what kind of result?

Comment: Result is 404. Like in my example.